# Background timer with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Need to get the timer going even if the app is running in backgroung.
Trying to use react-native-background-timer library to do so, but getting this error:

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNBackgroundTimer.setTimeout)

On some research got to know that I will have to eject expo to be able to use this.

Is there a way to do this with expo?

Answer (score 1):

Yes actually within Expo itself you can use their Background Fetch API to handle all background tasks, it uses TaskManager under the hood to do that. You don't need to use `react-native-background-timer`.

Further details of this API and application is found [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/background-fetch/).

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Too bad, it looks like this only supports a minimum interval of 10-15 minutes, which is too long for some use cases